# Apache to Nginx for following rule RewriteRule ^uploads - [L,NC]

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

How can I convert the line

```
RewriteRule ^uploads - [L,NC]
```

to Nginx? What does L and NC means? Thank you.

Comment: I haven't used apache in a long time, what is this rewrite rule trying to achieve ? rewriting `uploads` to what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you don't understand `apache` rewrites to begin with,

`L` means last (stop rewriting after this rule)

`NC` means no case (case insensitive)

What this rewrite trying to do ? I don't really know, seems incomplete to me, tell me what YOU want to do and I might help.

Comment: Thank you, I only had to know this part of the htaccess code. Have a nice day!